# How to prevent bootstrap modal to open when a modal is active

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have multiple modal in my project and some modal will open via javascript. I need if any modal is in open state no other modal will open. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to launch all your modals via javascript/jquery then you can check with

```
if ($('.modal .in').length() > 0) {
    //at least one open modal detected
    return;
else {
    //show modal
}
```

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer